# How to calculate storage required per node in a cluster setup with redundancy

Tags: math, memory

We have a cluster with 5 nodes where we store objects of different sizes with 3 copies for redundancy. I want to calculate the maximum storage I need to allocate for each node for a given number of objects and their sizes. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see this as a question appropriate for here, it doesn't seem to be programming-related. Also, what have you tried to answer this? It sounds like the answer is pretty simple: `3 * sum(object.size for object in objects)` (based on the little information here).

Comment: @ThomasJager Since the objects are equally distributed across the cluster since only 3 copies are required, sum(object.size for object in objects) is significantly more than what is required.

Comment: Then the maximum storage you could possibly need would be the sum of the object sizes; there's not really enough context to do any better. If the distribution of objects is "smart", then you could do something like sort the list of objects, group them into groups of 5, take the largest, 3 of each group, sum those, and sum that sum for each group of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try give memory and then limit the data that you wanna store in cache and see how much its all adding up to then you can determine how much you need for your store. Use max entries setting in the cache.